# firebase returns empty item

Tags: java, android, firebase

I am currently trying to make an activity called add job. The first part of the activity is designed to locate the care you are working on. I was hoping to do this by searching for the reg of the car.

So I have created an activity called add_car, where I add the details of the car to my data base. This all works, it uses the registration as the main key, then has other children that help distinguish the vehicle. So once a car is added this is how my data base looks:

```
Cars
----->

Kj65YHT (madeup reg for example)
 --->

manufacturer ford

model fiesta

doors 2

enginesize 1600

reg Kj65YHT
```

The data adds and removes from my database fine, but when I try to search for the reg after it has been added the list, it returns about 7 empty items. Here is my code:

Add_Job activity

```
public class Add_Job extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
private Button btnsubmit;
private EditText etreg;
private FirebaseDatabase db;
private DatabaseReference dbref;
private ListView mlv;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add__job);


    mlv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.mlv);
    btnsubmit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnsubmit);
    btnsubmit.setOnClickListener(this);
    etreg = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etreg);
    db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();


}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()){
        case R.id.btnsubmit:
locateRegistration();
            break;
    }
}

 private void locateRegistration(){
    String reg = etreg.getText().toString().trim();
    String Cars = "Cars";
    dbref = db.getReference().child(Cars).child(reg);
   HarropChildListener listner = new 
HarropChildListener(mlv,Add_Job.this,dbref);
    dbref.addChildEventListener(listner);
}
}
```

ChildEventListener class

```
public class HarropChildListener implements ChildEventListener {
private ListView mlv;

private static ArrayList<String> CAR_COLOUR;
private static ArrayList<String> AMOUNT_DOORS;
private static ArrayList<String> ENGINE_SIZE;
private static ArrayList<String> FUEL_TYPE;
private static ArrayList<String> CAR_MANUFACTURER;
private static ArrayList<String> CAR_MODEL;
private static ArrayList<String> CAR_REGISTRATION;
private Context mContext;
private dataListAdapter apkData;
private DatabaseReference ref;


public HarropChildListener(){

}

public HarropChildListener(ListView mlv,Context context, DatabaseReference dbref){
    this.mlv = mlv;
    this.mContext = context;
    this.ref = dbref;
    Log.i("Event","Started");

    CAR_COLOUR = new ArrayList<>();
    AMOUNT_DOORS = new ArrayList<>();
    ENGINE_SIZE = new ArrayList<>();
    FUEL_TYPE = new ArrayList<>();
    CAR_MANUFACTURER = new ArrayList<>();
    CAR_MODEL = new ArrayList<>();
    CAR_REGISTRATION = new ArrayList<>();

}
@Override
public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
    if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
        Log.i("Event", "Added");
        String a,b,c,d,e,f,g;
        a = dataSnapshot.child("colour").getValue(String.class);
        b = dataSnapshot.child("doors").getValue(String.class);
        c = dataSnapshot.child("enginesize").getValue(String.class);
        d = dataSnapshot.child("fuel").getValue(String.class);
        e = dataSnapshot.child("manufacturer").getValue(String.class);
        f = dataSnapshot.child("model").getValue(String.class);
        g = dataSnapshot.child("reg").getValue(String.class);

        CAR_COLOUR.add(a);
        AMOUNT_DOORS.add(b);
        ENGINE_SIZE.add(c);
        FUEL_TYPE.add(d);
        CAR_MANUFACTURER.add(e);
        CAR_MODEL.add(f);
        CAR_REGISTRATION.add(g);

        final String[] colours = CAR_COLOUR.toArray(new String[CAR_COLOUR.size()]);
        String[] doors = AMOUNT_DOORS.toArray(new String[AMOUNT_DOORS.size()]);
        String[] engine = ENGINE_SIZE.toArray(new String[ENGINE_SIZE.size()]);
        final String[] man = CAR_MANUFACTURER.toArray(new String[CAR_MANUFACTURER.size()]);
        final String[] model = CAR_MODEL.toArray(new String[CAR_MODEL.size()]);
        final String[] fuel = FUEL_TYPE.toArray(new String[FUEL_TYPE.size()]);
        final String[] reg = CAR_REGISTRATION.toArray(new String[CAR_REGISTRATION.size()]);
        apkData = new dataListAdapter(mContext, colours,fuel,man,model,reg,engine,doors);


        mlv.setAdapter(apkData);
        apkData.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
}

@Override
public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

}

@Override
public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

}

@Override
public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

}

@Override
public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

}
}
```

DatalistAdapter class

```
public class dataListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
String[] Colour, FuelType;
String[] Manufacturer,Model,Reg,EngineSize ,Doors;
Context mContext;
TextView tv1,tv2,tv3,tv4,tv5,tv6,tv7;

public dataListAdapter() {
    Colour = null;
    FuelType = null;
    Manufacturer = null;
    Model = null;
    Reg = null;
    EngineSize = null;
    Doors = null;
}

public dataListAdapter(Context c, String[] colour, String[] fuel, String[] manufacturer,String[]model,String[]reg,String[]engineSize, String[] doors) {
    Colour = colour;
    FuelType = fuel;
    Manufacturer = manufacturer;
    Model = model;
    Reg = reg;
    EngineSize = engineSize;
    Doors = doors;

    this.mContext = c;




}

public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return Reg.length;
}

public Object getItem(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


    final View row;


    if (convertView == null) {

            row = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.custom, parent, false);

    } else {
        row = convertView;
    }


    tv1 =  row.findViewById(R.id.tvcolour);
    tv2 = row.findViewById(R.id.tvfuel);
    tv3 = row.findViewById(R.id.tvmanufacture);
    tv4 = row.findViewById(R.id.tvmodel);
    tv5 = row.findViewById(R.id.tvreg);
    tv6  = row.findViewById(R.id.tvengine);
    tv7 = row.findViewById(R.id.tvdoors);


    tv1.setText(Colour[position]);
    tv2.setText(FuelType[position]);
    tv3.setText(Manufacturer[position]);
    tv4.setText(Model[position]);
    tv5.setText(Reg[position]);
    tv6.setText(EngineSize[position]);
    tv7.setText(Doors[position]);
    return (row);
}
```

### Edit

After loads of testing and amendment this is where I am at. If I remove the line the reg child from my the end of my Database ref:

```
dbref = db.getReference().child(Cars).child(reg);
```

Like this:

```
dbref = db.getReference().child(Cars);
```

it populates the list with all the data in my Cars section. I just want the car I am searching for. I just don't understand, why when I search the child(reg) it returns blank.

### Edit 2

After further testing, I found that when adding the car data if add an extra child for the reg to go into it works. So now the database looks like this:

```
Cars---->

Kj65YHT (madeup reg for example)
 --->
Kj65YHT (This is the extra child ive had to add surly this is wrong?)
 --->

manufacturer ford

model fiesta

doors 2

enginesize 1600

reg Kj65YHT
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I could not fix it to make it acceptable, and probably no one can.

Comment: well done on a 2 year old question

Comment: I think now you could already re-formulate it into a comprehensible form. If you edit your own question, automatically a voting about its reopen will be started. Just use round sentences.